# Is possible print on guild channel who banned the Bot, before bot actually leave the server on Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I build a simple Discord.py bot to joke some friends, but sometimes someone ban my bot and I wonder if I can print the guilty before bot actually leave the server.

After few tests, notice that I can print on channel that bot is **being banned** with:

```py
async def report(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_LISTEN_ID)
    await channel.send(message)

@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, member):
    if member.id == bot.user.id:
        await report(f'HEELLPPPP! SOMEONE IS BANNING ME, DAMN IT!')
    else:
        await report('<:pepecop:1114663204971360316>')
```

Bot prints the message before leave the server. But when I try fetch who banned him, I guess isn't time enough and bot leave the server before the answer:

```py
async def report(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_LISTEN_ID)
    await channel.send(message)

@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, member):
    if member.id == bot.user.id:
        ban_log = await guild.audit_logs().find(lambda log: log.action is discord.AuditLogAction.ban)
        await report(f'HEELLPPPP! <@{ban_log.user.id}> IS BANNING ME, DAMN IT!')
    else:
        await report('<:pepecop:1114663204971360316>')
```

Here nothing is printed on channel and bot leave the server. So, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically this is not possible as the only way to find out who banned your bot is by looking at the audit log. However, once your bot is banned, it is no longer authorized to access the server's audit log.
That is, your bot can find out who banned another user, but not who banned itself.